# What happens if we add one more character after the basic_string reaches max_size in c++

Tags: c++, libstdc++

> `#0`  0x00008432126cda64 in `std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::empty() const ()` from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6

the code is crashing at the libstdc++ empty() function

```
bool empty() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // test if sequence is empty
    return (this->_Mysize == 0);
    }
```

this is the standard empty function

Comment: This would be a good place for a [Complete, minimal, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where in ***your*** code do the crash happen? What are you doing there?

Comment: What does testing **empty** have to do with adding one more than **max_size**?

Answer (score 3):

What does happen is defined in the Stadnard [[string.require/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.require#1):

> If any operation would cause `size()` to exceed `max_­size()`, that operation **throws an exception object of type `length_­error`**.

It's not clear what this question is about since the title does not correspond with the text/code. The only operation that can fail in `empty` is dereferencing `this`. Therefore, it seems that you are calling `empty` on an invalid pointer, such as for an object that no longer exists (has been destroyed).